# Emacs ignoring setq for line numbers

Tags: emacs, line-numbers

I am trying to set up my `.emacs` to use relative line numbering, and so I have included:

```lisp
(setq display-line-numbers 'relative)
```

to my `.emacs`, however this is being ignored on load. Line numbers appear, however they are simply absolute line numbers, as opposed to relative.

Interestingly, when I run `M-x load-file .emacs`, it actually evaluates this line (as well as the rest of the file) and the line numbers become relative, however this doesn't happen the first time.

Below is my entire `.emacs`, and the line in question is on line 95/96:

```lisp
(package-initialize)

(load "~/.emacs.rc/rc.el")
(load "~/.emacs.rc/misc-rc.el")


(defun rc/get-default-font ()
  (cond
   ((eq system-type 'windows-nt) "Consolas-13")
   ((eq system-type 'gnu/linux) "Iosevka-24")))

(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist `(font . ,(rc/get-default-font)))

(tool-bar-mode 0)
(menu-bar-mode 0)
(scroll-bar-mode 0)
(column-number-mode 1)
(show-paren-mode 1)

(rc/require-theme 'gruber-darker)
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(package-selected-packages
   '(svelte-mode tramp-mode elixir-mode evil move-text nasm-mode company yasnippet multiple-cursors magit haskell-mode ido-completing-read+ smex gruber-darker-theme dash-functional dash)))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )

(eval-after-load 'zenburn
  (set-face-attribute 'line-number nil :inherit 'default))

(rc/require 'smex 'ido-completing-read+)

(require 'ido-completing-read+)

(ido-mode 1)
(ido-everywhere 1)
(ido-ubiquitous-mode 1)

(global-set-key (kbd "M-x") 'smex)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-c M-x") 'execute-extended-command)

;;; C mode
(setq-default c-basic-offset 4
              c-default-style '((java-mode . "java")
                                (awk-mode . "awk")
                                (other . "bsd")))

(add-hook 'c-mode-hook (lambda ()
                         (interactive)
                         (c-toggle-comment-style -1)))

;;; Elisp

(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook
          '(lambda ()
             (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-j")
                            (quote eval-print-last-sexp))))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("Cask" . emacs-lisp-mode))

;;; Haskell mode
(rc/require 'haskell-mode)

(setq haskell-process-type 'cabal-new-repl)
(setq haskell-process-log t)

(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'haskell-ident-mode)
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'interactive-haskell-mode)
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'haskell-doc-mode)
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'hindent-mode)

;;; Whitespace mode
(defun rc/set-up-whitespace-handling ()
  (interactive)
  (whitespace-mode 1)
  (add-to-list 'write-file-fucntions 'delete-trailing-whitespace))

(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'rc/set-up-whitespace-handling)
(add-hook 'java-mode-hook 'rc/set-up-whitespace-handling)
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode 'rc/set-up-whitespace-handling)
(add-hook 'rust-mode-hook 'rc/set-up-whitespace-handling)
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'rc/set-up-whitespace-handling)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'rc/set-up-whitespace-handling)
(add-hook 'erlang-mode-hook 'rc/set-up-whitespace-handling)
(add-hook 'asm-mode-hook 'rc/set-up-whitespace-handling)
(add-hook 'nasm-mode-hook 'rc/set-up-whitespace-handling)


(global-display-line-numbers-mode)
(setq display-line-numbers 'relative)

;;; Magit

(rc/require 'cl-lib)
(rc/require 'magit)

(setq magit-auto-revert-mode nil)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c m s") 'magit-status)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c m l") 'magit-log)

;;; Multiple Cursors

(rc/require 'multiple-cursors)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-c C-S-c") 'mc/edit-lines)
(global-set-key (kbd "C->") 'mc/mark-next-like-this)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<") 'mc/mark-previous-like-this)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-<") 'mc/mark-all-like-this)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-\"") 'mc/skip-to-next-like-this)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-:") 'mc/skip-to-previous-like-this)

;;; Dired

(require 'dired-x)
(setq dired-omit-files
      (concat dired-omit-files "\\|^\\..+$"))
(setq-default dired-dwim-target t)
(setq dired-listing-switches "-alh")

;;; Yasnippet

(rc/require 'yasnippet)

(require 'yasnippet)

(setq yas/triggers-in-field nil)
(setq yas-snipped-dirs '("~/.emacs.snippets/"))

(yas-global-mode 1)

;;; Word-Wrap

(defun rc/enable-word-wrap ()
  (interactive)
  (toggle-word-wrap 1))

(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook 'rc/enable-word-wrap)

;;; Company Mode
(rc/require 'company)
(require 'company)

(global-company-mode)

;;; NASM mode
(rc/require 'nasm-mode)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.asm\\'" . nasm-mode))

;;; TeX mode
(add-hook 'tex-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (interactive)
            (add-to-list 'tex-verbatim-environments "code")))

;;; Move Text
(rc/require 'move-text)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-p") 'move-text-up)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-n") 'move-text-down)

(rc/require
 'rust-mode
 'markdown-mode
 'elixir-mode
 'svelte-mode
 )

;;; Svelte Mode

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.svelte\\'" . svelte-mode))

;;; Kill all buffers

(defun kill-all-buffers ()
  (interactive)
  (dolist (cur (buffer-list))
    (kill-buffer cur)))

(defun close-current-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (kill-buffer (buffer-name)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x K") 'kill-all-buffers)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-w") 'close-current-buffer)

(defun indent-whole-file ()
  (interactive)
  (indent-region (point-min) (point-max)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-<tab>") 'indent-whole-file)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-=") 'text-scale-increase)
(global-set-key (kbd "C--") 'text-scale-decrease)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read this part of the doc for `display-line-numbers`:

> This variable automatically becomes **buffer-local when set outside Custom**.
> However, **setting it through Custom** sets the default value.

You're using `setq` with a user option - not a great idea in general. Use `M-x customize-option` instead, or use function `customize-set-variable` or `custom-set-variables`.

Unless you do some tricky finagling, you can't depend on your `setq` being evaluated in any particular buffer. And anyway, you apparently want to set the **default** value of the option. `setq-default` sets the default value of a variable. But anyway, use one of the `custom*` functions or (even better), `M-x customize-option`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `display-line-numbers-type` instead as per the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Display-Custom.html)

"The command M-x display-line-numbers-mode provides a convenient way to turn on display of line numbers. This mode has a globalized variant, global-display-line-numbers-mode. The user option display-line-numbers-type controls which sub-mode of line-number display, described above, these modes will activate."

So following works.

```
(global-display-line-numbers-mode 1)
(setq display-line-numbers-type 'relative)
```